# Import Instagram post to Wordpress blog post

Tags: plugins, posts, loop, import

I'm looking for a way how I can import an Instagram post to a Wordpress post.

So to make it clear: I'm NOT looking for a Instagram Feed plugin. I need to import an Instagram post to a Wordpress blog posts separately.

This is because I need a post loop with multiple categories where one of them is an Instagram post.

So how can I do that? If there is a plugin for this, that will be fine. All suggestions are welcome. I prefer the most simple solution obviously.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need anyway to create an Instagram application for that and build a small API interface.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not currently aware of other ways rather then:

- Creating an Instagram App
- Get an access token
- Build a small API handler

Something like this to put in your `functions.php`:

```
function my_instagram()
{
    $transient_key = 'instagram_data';
    $feed_data = get_transient( $transient_key );
    if( false === $feed_data ) {
        $feed_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&count=4'));
        if ( is_array( $feed_data->data ) ) {
            set_transient( $transient_key, $feed_data->data, 60*60*24 );
        }
    }
    return $feed_data;
}
```

Later of course you can manipulate your `$feed_data` as you need. Adjust the transient according to your requirements.

It's called feed because it is what it is. I'm afraid though they lately restricted the endpoints. Read more https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/.

You can generate intagram access tokens here https://instagram.pixelunion.net/.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a tutorial for this?

Comment: I think the best place to start would be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram then the function in the example works out of the box. You can call it anywhere in your theme like `my_instagram()` and it will output the feed data.